# How to render a string from structural directive?

Tags: angular

`ViewContainerRef` offers methods `createEmbeddedView` (which accepts `TemplateRef`, for rendering templates) and `createComponent` (which accepts `ComponentFactory`, for rendering components). But what about a simple **string**?

The only workaround I see is to have a `DummyComponent` and then feed a `document.createTextNode('string')` to `projectableNodes`.

```
@Component({ template: `<ng-content></ng-content>` }) class DummyComponent {}
```

```
const dummyComponentFactory = this.cfr.resoveComponentFactory(DummyComponent)
const nodes = [[document.createTextNode('string')]]
this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(dummyComponentFactory, 0, injector, nodes)
```

But this is just abusing the API and has an enormous overhead for rendering a simple string.

Comment: why not create a simple <ng-template><span>{{inputString</span></ng-template>, and then using the createEmbeddedView function?

Comment: Where would I create it? A directive has no template.

Comment: I understand your point, but I can't think of a valid use case. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I'm creating something akin to `*ngFor`, but with a separator between (like a `.join`). Commonly, a separator is a simple string, like a comma. I'd like to be able to write `<x 
 *ngJoin="let item of items; separator: ','"></x>` instead of `<x *ngJoin="let item of items; separator: separatorTpl"></x> <ng-template #separatorTpl>,</ng-template>`. Also I'd like to provide comma as the default value of `@Input() separator`. If its type is a `TemplateRef`, there's no way of giving it a default value (impossible to create TemplateRef from code -- or is it?).

Comment: You want to add some deafult value inside ng-template if it's a type TemplateRef?

Comment: No, I don't have a TemplateRef because I'm in a directive. If I could create a TemplateRef from class code, that would be a correct answer since it would solve the problem.

Comment: So basically you want to have something in template for a array to be displayed as a string with a passable separator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to achieve it via directive, its possible. Please refer to directive code below :-

```
import {
  Directive,
  Input,
  NgIterable,
  OnChanges,
  OnInit,
  Renderer2,
  TemplateRef,
  ViewContainerRef
} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[ngJoin]"
})
export class NgJoinDirective<T, U extends NgIterable<T> = NgIterable<T>>
  implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() ngJoinOf: any[];
  @Input() ngJoinSeparator: string = ",";
  constructor(
    private _viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private _template: TemplateRef<any>,
    private renderer2: Renderer2
  ) {}

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.createText();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createText();
  }

  createText() {
    if (this.ngJoinOf) {
      this._viewContainer.clear();
      console.log(this.ngJoinOf);
      const container = this._template.createEmbeddedView({});
      const parentNode = container.rootNodes[0];
      const textNode = this.renderer2.createText(
        this.ngJoinOf.join(this.ngJoinSeparator)
      );
      this.renderer2.insertBefore(parentNode, textNode, parentNode.firstChild);
      this._viewContainer.insert(container);
    }
  }
}
```

and used in html like below :-

```
<p *ngJoin="let item of arr;separator: '/'">
```

if you will not give separator it will take , as default separator.

**Working Stackblitz :-**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rumkzc?file=src/app/app.component.html

If you are just looking to print array via join in template using a separator, pipe will be a ideal choice instead of directive. Such a pipe is provided by a library.

https://github.com/fknop/angular-pipes

The pipe name is join.

**Note :- I have not handled, any edge cases, you might want to handle.**

Comment: This seems to do the trick, thanks. The issue with pipe is that, while a separator is a string, the elements themselves are in my case not strings, but custom chunks of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a pipe to transform your data?

In any case, `ViewContainerRef` can render only components, so - you can create a component with an Input of the string you want to show, and create it dynamically. Something like that:

```
@Component({ template: `{{text}}` }) class DummyComponent {
   @Input text: string;
}
```

But I think a pipe is more suitable for your situation.

Comment: See the fourth comment on the question. Also your answer is already mentioned in my question.

Comment: Also not sure about the statement “`ViewContainerRef` can render only components”. It can render views as well (`createEmbeddedView`). Maybe `Renderer` can help somehow? There were talks and promises by the team that **Ivy** would allow us to create templates in code, but I don't see it anywhere now that Ivy is stable -- have these ideas been discarded?